# Passing an arbitrary number of parameters to a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, args

I have a python function which takes as input an arbitrary number of parameters. I beleive this is implemented via `*args` (thanks @Anurag Wagh for pointing this out). I would like to be able to pass to it a list of values. Here is the specific code I have:

```
from sympy import solve_poly_system, symbols
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
print(solve_poly_system([y**2 - x**3 + 1, y*x], x, y))
```

Instead of passing `x` and `y` to `solve_poly_system`, I want to be able to pass it a list `L` something like so:

```
print(solve_poly_system([y**2 - x**3 + 1, y*x], L))
```

where `L = [x,y]`.

Is this possible? Please note, although I am interested in the specific case of the `solve_poly_system` function, I am more broadly interested in the passing a list to any function in python that takes an arbitrary number of inputs.

To put this another way, I want to know how to pass a list of values to a function which takes `*args` as input. In particular I am interested in the case where the length of the list is not known until run time and may change during run time.

Comment: I think you are looking for `*args` type function. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am talking about, however the post you link to doesn't answer my question. I will edit my question shortly to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you know how to use `*args` in function definition and you are looking for a way to pass all the elements of a list to that function regardless of the length of the list. If that's your question, then here's your answer:

```
def function(x, *args):
    print(x)
    print(args)

x = 10
l = [5, 6, 7, 8]
function(x, *l)
```

**Output:**

```
10
(5, 6, 7, 8)
```